# How can I do an EF query on a table to show results only when there's no link to a child table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Word 
{
    public System.Guid WordId { get; set; } // WordId (Primary key)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name (length: 20)
    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WordForm> WordForms { get; set; } // WordForm.FK_WordFormWord 
}

public class WordForm
{
    public System.Guid WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (Primary key)
    public System.Guid WordId { get; set; } // WordId
    public string Definition { get; set; } // Definition (length: 500)
    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; } // FK_WordFormWord
}
```

The word table has some words with matching WordForms and some that have none. What I need is to get a list of words that have no corresponding WordForms.

Here's the code I have so far. I know how to add a simple .Where but this need I have is something I've not seen how to do:

```
   var words = db.Words
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
```

Can someone tell me how I can modify this code to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Sub Query should work:

```
var words = db.Words
            .Where(w=> !db.WordForms.Any(z=> z.WordId == w.WordId))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the `Words` which has no `WordForms` like this :

```
var words = db.Words
            .Where(W => W.WordForms.Count == 0)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

this code works and not need to filter in any statement!

```
var words = db.Words.Where(e => !e.WordForms.Any())
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a left join

```
var words = (from w in db.Words
             join wf in db.WordForms
                 on w.WordId equals wf.WordId into wwf
             from x in wwf.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where x == null
             select w)
             .AsNoTracking()
             .ToList();
```